# $u \in W^{2,p}_\text{loc} \implies u \in C^{1,1}(K)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the theorem below, they state that a uniform bound on compact sets of $u \in W^{2,p}_{loc}$ will be enough to show that $u \in C^{1,1}$. How does one see this?

2.1: $\Delta u = f \chi_{u > 0}$

2.2: $f = \Delta \psi$

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images. What is $p$? What is (2.1)? What is (2.2)? Is it in any dimension?

Comment: I added definitions of 2.1 and 2.2. I guess $p > n$ where $n$ is the dimension. Sorry for the image post, I'll fix this later. Basically, I know for large enough $p$, there's some sobolev imedding into a Holder continuous space. But that's for $\alpha <1$. So I think something else is going on here.

Comment: @yoshi What is $\psi$? I assume $\Omega(u)$ is the support of $u$?

Comment: @Zeta-Squared $\psi$ is just some function. The point is that $f$ has a nice form -- like you can take 2 derivatives of some function then you obtain $f$. Perhaps the statement of the theorem confuses the issue. Basically I'm asking, if I have an almost everywhere bound on the second derivative -- can I say I have bound on the first derivative everywhere?